# Single Column From SHOW Command

Tags: mysql

I am using this to get my PRIMARY Index Columns.

```
SHOW INDEX FROM `table` WHERE Key_name='PRIMARY'
```

It returns a table with type, column_name, Key_name, etc.

I only want the `Column_name` column.

I tried:

```
SHOW INDEX.Column_name FROM `table` WHERE Key_name='PRIMARY'
```

But it did not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all columns from a PRIMARY KEY (in order) for `mydb.mytable`, run this:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.statistics
WHERE table_schema='mydb'
AND table_name='mytable'
AND index_name='PRIMARY'
ORDER BY seq_in_index;
```

To get all columns from a PRIMARY KEY (in order) for `mytable` in the current database, run this:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.statistics
WHERE table_schema=DATABASE()
AND table_name='mytable'
AND index_name='PRIMARY'
ORDER BY seq_in_index;
```

Here is a sample table:

```
mysql> show create table cacti.host_snmp_cache\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: host_snmp_cache
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `host_snmp_cache` (
  `host_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `snmp_query_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `field_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `field_value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `snmp_index` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `oid` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`host_id`,`snmp_query_id`,`field_name`,`snmp_index`),
  KEY `host_id` (`host_id`,`field_name`),
  KEY `snmp_index` (`snmp_index`),
  KEY `field_name` (`field_name`),
  KEY `field_value` (`field_value`),
  KEY `snmp_query_id` (`snmp_query_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Notice the PRIMARY KEY has 4 columns

Here is the query's execution:

```
mysql> SELECT column_name
    -> FROM information_schema.statistics
    -> WHERE table_schema='cacti'
    -> AND table_name='host_snmp_cache'
    -> AND index_name='PRIMARY'
    -> ORDER BY seq_in_index;
+---------------+
| column_name   |
+---------------+
| host_id       |
| snmp_query_id |
| field_name    |
| snmp_index    |
+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Using [**GROUP_CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), you can collect the column names into a CSV list

```
mysql> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name) PrimaryKeyColumns
    -> FROM information_schema.statistics
    -> WHERE table_schema='cacti'
    -> AND table_name='host_snmp_cache'
    -> AND index_name='PRIMARY'
    -> ORDER BY seq_in_index;
+---------------------------------------------+
| PrimaryKeyColumns                           |
+---------------------------------------------+
| host_id,snmp_query_id,field_name,snmp_index |
+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Perfect answer. I saw 3-4 other answers like this when searching and each one either did not work or my account did not have high enough permissions. This works perfectly :)